# module.createRequire webpack bundling

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am trying to bundle a node application into a single file.

However after inspecting the output of webpack after the bundling.

I found that one of the libraries uses `Module.createRequire` to load some module at runtime.
Inspecting the bundled code I understood that webpack doesn't replace `Module.createRequire(path).resolve` by `__webpack_require__` , which results in my application depending on node_module after being bundled.

I can think of a simple solution by modifying the code of the library and use `require` instead of `Module.createRequire`. But I prefer not to modify the library code cause that would add extra headache every time I want to update the library.

Secondly I am wondering if I replaced the following code `Module.createRequire(myPath)` by `require(myPath)` according to [Webpack Context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext) would webpack bundle all of the node_modules as the resulting expression `*` would match with all the modules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was mistaken about `Module.createRequire(path).resolve`. I thought it resolves the module but actually it is just resolving the path.

However what causing the issue is `require(path)`. For webpack that's a bundle without any context, so it generates `webpackEmptyContext` for it. Which does nothing but throwing an exception.

A hacky solution to go around that is to replace the `require` in the considered file by `__non_webpack_require__` as follows [Using dynamic require on node targets WITHOUT resolve or bundle the target module](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4175#issuecomment-450746682)

Of course you would have to copy the modules to the right path as they are not being bundled. You can use `webpacCopyPlugin` for that.

I am amazed that there is no official documentation concerning that behavior in the following documentation [Webpack Context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext), or anywhere else. And it looks like a scenario that could happen very often especially not having control of the code. I had to figured it out myself, and I hope I am mistaken, and I hope there is a cleaner way to do so.